# Famous pawn promotion matches

Tags: pawn-promotion, pawn-endgame, famous-games

Except for a famous match between Tigran Petrosian and Bobby fischer, I don't know of any famous chess match between top notch players which had some climactic pawn promotions . Could anyone here suggest a few more of matches of that kind?

Comment: Which Petrosian-Fisher game are you thinking about? The one with four queens?

Comment: I, too, don't know which game OP is talking about. @Ozy Could you please post the FEN either in your question or as an answer to this question?

Comment: Must read : https://timkr.home.xs4all.nl/chess2/minor.htm

Answer (score 10):

A game between McDonnell and De La Bourdonnais is very famous. Although no promotion was executed on the board, it is definitely the theme of the game.

```
      [FEN ""]
      [Event "London m4 ;HCL 18"]
      [Site "16"]
      [Date "1834.??.??"]
      [EventDate "?"]
      [Round "62"]
      [Result "0-1"]
      [White "Alexander McDonnell"]
      [Black "Louis Charles Mahe De La Bourdonnais"]
      [ECO "B32"]
      [WhiteElo "?"]
      [BlackElo "?"]
      [PlyCount "74"]
      [StartPly "74"]

1.e4 c5 2.Nf3 Nc6 3.d4 cxd4 4.Nxd4 e5 5.Nxc6 bxc6 6.Bc4 Nf6
7.Bg5 Be7 8.Qe2 d5 9.Bxf6 Bxf6 10.Bb3 O-O 11.O-O a5 12.exd5
cxd5 13.Rd1 d4 14.c4 Qb6 15.Bc2 Bb7 16.Nd2 Rae8 17.Ne4 Bd8
18.c5 Qc6 19.f3 Be7 20.Rac1 f5 21.Qc4+ Kh8 22.Ba4 Qh6 23.Bxe8
fxe4 24.c6 exf3 25.Rc2 Qe3+ 26.Kh1 Bc8 27.Bd7 f2 28.Rf1 d3
29.Rc3 Bxd7 30.cxd7 e4 31.Qc8 Bd8 32.Qc4 Qe1 33.Rc1 d2 34.Qc5
Rg8 35.Rd1 e3 36.Qc3 Qxd1 37.Rxd1 e2 0-1
```

Answer (score 3):

There is also a famous miniature between Spassky and Larsen, that ends with a pawn promotion:

```
      [FEN ""]
[Event "USSR vs. Rest of the World"]
[Site "Belgrade SRB"]
[Date "1970.03.31"]
[EventDate "1970.03.29"]
[Round "2.1"]
[Result "0-1"]
[White "Bent Larsen"]
[Black "Boris Spassky"]
[ECO "A01"]
[WhiteElo "?"]
[BlackElo "?"]
[PlyCount "34"]

1. b3 e5 2. Bb2 Nc6 3. c4 Nf6 4. Nf3 e4 5. Nd4 Bc5 6. Nxc6
dxc6 7. e3 Bf5 8. Qc2 Qe7 9. Be2 O-O-O 10. f4 Ng4 11. g3 h5
12. h3 h4 13. hxg4 hxg3 14. Rg1 Rh1 15. Rxh1 g2 16. Rf1 Qh4+
17. Kd1 gxf1=Q+ 0-1
```

Answer (score 3):

One famous game is the one in which Alekhine sacrificed three queens. I pulled the moves from [chessgames.com](https://www.chessgames.com/perl/chessgame?gid=1012099)

```
[Title "Efim Bogoljubov-Alexander Alekhine, Hastings, Hastings England, 9/22/1922"]
[FEN ""]

1. d4 f5 2. c4 Nf6 3. g3 e6 4. Bg2 Bb4+ 5. Bd2 Bxd2+ 6. Nxd2 Nc6 7. Ngf3 O-O 8. O-O d6 9. Qb3 Kh8 10. Qc3 e5 11. e3 a5 12. b3 Qe8 13. a3 Qh5 14. h4 Ng4 15. Ng5 Bd7 16. f3 Nf6 17. f4 e4 18. Rfd1 h6 19. Nh3 d5 20. Nf1 Ne7 21. a4 Nc6 22. Rd2 Nb4 23. Bh1 Qe8 24. Rg2 dxc4 25. bxc4 Bxa4 26.Nf2 Bd7 27. Nd2 b5 28. Nd1 Nd3 29. Rxa5 b4 30. Rxa8 bxc3 31. Rxe8 c2 32. Rxf8+ Kh7 33. Nf2 c1=Q+ 34. Nf1 Ne1 35. Rh2 Qxc4 36. Rb8 Bb5 37. Rxb5 Qxb5 38. g4 Nf3+ 39. Bxf3 exf3 40. gxf5 Qe2 41. d5 Kg8 42. h5 Kh7 43. e4 Nxe4 44. Nxe4 Qxe4 45. d6 cxd6 46. f6 gxf6 47. Rd2 Qe2 48. Rxe2 fxe2 49. Kf2 exf1=Q+ 50. Kxf1 Kg7 51. Ke2 Kf7 52. Ke3 Ke6 53. Ke4 d5+ 0-1
```